# Firebase RealTime DB - Query returns an old DataSnapshot - and not new keys unless restarting the app

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I retrieve 10 keys each time from my sorted DB.

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("CarsForSale/")
   .OrderByKey().EndAt(lastSavedKey).LimitToLast(10).GetValueAsync()
```

It works fine.  But when new items are added to the database, I can't retrieve those new values unless I reset the app.
If I don't use the query `.OrderByKey().EndAt().LimitToLast`, I do get the new keys from the DB without resetting the app

My guess is when I query the value at a location, it locally caches it.
My solution for a while was using `KeepSynced(true)` and it worked.

```
DatabaseReference dtr = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(path);
dtr.KeepSynced(true);
dtr.OrderByKey().EndAt(lastKey).LimitToLast(10).GetValueAsync()
```

But it made my app very slow because that syncs and caches the entire DB reference.  So instead I tried to apply KeepSynced only on the query of every sorted 10 keys but it doesn't make sense.

What can I do to make sure when I query keys from the DB to get the latest keys without having to restart my app or make it slow with caching?

Answer (score 0):

> But when new items are added to the database, I can't retrieve those new values unless I reset the app.

This is because the `GetValueAsync()` first gets the values from the cache, and only then updates the cache. It's an annoying behavior that unfortunately can't be changed, and that I explained here: [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195). I also just updated that answer for the newer `get`/`getData` methods on Android/iOS, but I don't think that exists in the C#/Unity SDKs yet.

The options I explained in the linked answer apply here too, so I'm going to close your question as a duplicate. If you have additional question, just comment here (if it's about your code/C#) or there (if it's about the general caching behavior).

Comment: Thanks. So I really don't know what to do now.  How can I get updated values? it's a basic question. When does the cache get updated?   KeepSynced- doesn't work properly as I explained here- https://stackoverflow.com/q/68659086/3430889

Comment: If the problem is as you've described there, let's keep the discussion going there too.